# Overflow scroll e flex juntos

Tags: html, css, rolamento, flexbox

Olá, estou tentando aplicar um overflow scroll em um elemento que esta sendo posicionado com flex, mas notei que não está funcionando, pois ele está expandindo até comportar todos os seus elementos (provavelmente por que não foi definido height). Como eu faria o scroll funcionar devidamente sem mexer na flexbox?

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex;">
  <div style="flex-grow: 100; border-radius: 8px; border: solid 1px #E4E4E4; background-color: #F7F7F7; margin: 1em; overflow: hidden; display: flex;">
    <!-- Este elemeto esta expandindo -->
    <tab-panel style="max-width: 15em; flex-grow: 100; background-color: #F7F7F7; cursor: pointer; overflow: scroll;">
      Elementos...
    </tab-panel>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bom, eu não sei qual o "height" que eu deveria definir, pois a flexbox está fazendo isso pra mim. Como proceder?

Comment: Mas esse tab-panel vai ter uma altura ou não? Pelo que eu testei aqui quando o conteúdo é grande ele da o scroll normalmente... o que vc queria, como vc quer que ele se comporte?

Comment: A mesma altura do elemento pai. Eu consegui fazer uma gambiarrinha usando height: 96vh, mas nao sei como isso vai se comportar em diferentes tamanhos de tela

Comment: Jovem mas ele já está com a altura do pai.... Acho que não estou entendendo o problema rss, eu coloquei um tanto de conteúdo no tab-panel e ele ficou do tamanho do pai e com o scroll...

Comment: Sim, ele ja esta com a altura do pai. Mas quando ele contem muitos elementos, em vez de usar o scroll ele expande o seu tamanho